# How to capture windows user details using PHP

Tags: php, windows

I want to know where do i get or how do i get the user details
such as username, id number and email when he/she logs-in in an intranet of
a corporate network using PHP?

I want to use those details to automatically authenticate user to the web-application
i am developing.

I have read about AUTH_USER but where or how do i access the variable?

Comment: Looks like Impossible stuff !

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using?

Comment: That data is not provided by the browser; even if it was, how would you validate it without a password?

Comment: I would like to use the username,id number,and email ad to authenticate. I dont need to authenticate the password since it was already authenticated upon logging in in the windows OS itself. I just want to know who was logged in and what his/her detail are like the username,idnumber,emailaddress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do most of what you want via [PHP LDAP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php) functions. The only catch is that you would need to get a unique item to each user. You will have to do a little more research, but I am pretty sure that if you use IIS as the webserver rather than Apache, there is some quirk or trick to getting the logon/username of the person on the other end - which you could then use to query against LDAP in the following manner:

```
<?php
// $ds is a valid link identifier for a directory server

// $person is all or part of a person's name, eg "Jo"

$dn = "o=My Company, c=US";
$filter="(|(sn=$person*)(givenname=$person*))";
$justthese = array("ou", "sn", "givenname", "mail");

$sr=ldap_search($ds, $dn, $filter, $justthese);

$info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);

echo $info["count"]." entries returned\n";
?>
```

Apache will just return AUTH_USER as blank. A workaround would be to create a one off request for their logon, store it in a cookie and use the same LDAP queries to get up-to-date info on the user.

Comment: @Jayzee Yeah, I think the trick is to use IIS which then has some semi-insecurity where the Microsoft products talk to one another where they shouldn't and you can take advantage of that. A quick bit of googling just helped. The AUTH_USER you are referring to is that IIS trick to get the user info. Once you have that, you can query your LDAP servers (Assuming the company has them which is likely)

Comment: Actually sir, there is two http server on the server, there is IIS and Apache. Though all the tools I developed are using the Apache, and some other developers used the IIS in there web-app tools. Is there no way to get the user details when my http server is apache?

Comment: @Jayzee No, when you try to use that in Apache it just returns empty. Also, see edit for a possible (but not fantastic) workaround.

Comment: Its a good information to start with sir. Highly appreciated.

Comment: @Jayzee Okay, good luck. Just be aware that short of actually verifying a user through their own input you can't be totally certain. This method *may* at some point be "closed" as a security loophole in IIS. It has been around for a while though, without MS looking like it is a priority, so it might hang around for years to come yet.